# How to check for existence of an XCTestCase subclass using the subclass name

Tags: swift, subclass, xctestcase

My unit tests are divided into different subclasses of `XCTestCase`.
For a specific initialization of the app I want to check if a unit test of a certain `XCTestCase` subclass has been started.
Such a subclass is defined using

```
class SomeTestCase: XCTestCase { //… }
```

I know that I can check for the existence of `XCTestCase` using

```
NSClassFromString("XCTestCase") != nil
```

This works. However,

```
NSClassFromString("SomeTestCase") != nil
```

does not work.

Why does this check not work for a subclass of `XCTestCase`?
How could I check for its existence?

PS: I know I could set a launch argument in the scheme. But then I had to use different schemes for the different subclasses, which is not feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the difference in behaviour is because `SomeTestCase` is a Swift class and its class name will include the module in which it is defined.

If you use `NSStringFromClass(SomeTestCase.self)` then you can see the name that is being used.

Alternatively, you can give the test class an explicit name to use in the Objective-C environment:

```
@objc(SomeTestCase)
class SomeTestCase: XCTestCase { //… }
```